# Remove pattern match in for loop using shell script

Tags: shell

I ve got the iteration results  using for loop like....

```
city: Hyberabad
city: Hyberabad-Rural 
city: Hyberabad-Rural
```

But expected result to print is

```
Hyderabad
```

Can some one here suggest.

Comment: pls show an example of input, more important, the codes you've written so far.

Comment: Why do you expect `Hyperabad`? Might be any city without a `-`, just `head -1`, any city that occurs three times, unique cities, first word starting with a capital, any word that only occurs once, or some other requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string in every iteration

```
cities=$(echo $IN | tr "-" "\n")
```

where IN is the string to split (like 'city: Hyberabad').
Then just take the first value of the returned array $cities

```
echo "> $cities[$1]"
```